# Angular 4 - Limit user input for specific range

Tags: angular, forms

I want to have simple number input component that allows only for numbers from specific range.

I use HTML min/max attributes that works when user is using input "arrows"

```
<input type="number" style="width: 100px" [(ngModel)]="value" min="0" max="99" />
```

And I am checking also the values when propagating it further to application:

```
export class AppInput {
  _v: number;

  @Input()
  get value(): number {
    return this._v;
  }
  set value(v) {
    if (v > 99) {
      v = 99;
    }
    this._v = v;
    this.valueChange.emit(v);
  }
  @Output() valueChange = new EventEmitter<number>();
}
```

When user write directly to the input, when he e.g. press `0` when value is `10` - input is correctly changed to `99`. However when he continues, content of input is changed to `990` (even though model is correctly 99).

How can I limit user what he can enter into input component?

Sample project: https://codesandbox.io/s/w23900kx05

Comment: You can also use a custom pipe to achieve that.

Comment: The sample project seems working for me. So I can't reproduce

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't understand why do you need an `Input` property `value` for your custom Input from the parent. (Probably you want some default value?).

Coming to the solution of your question. Why is your view(input box) not updating even if the model has the correct maximum value? Let's see it this way:

You have a property `value` which is bound to the input box. So when the input value changes, this is how `value's` data will be updated. Consider that initially `value = 0`, then you input `1` in the input box, due to `2-way binding`,  `value` will be updated with one. Will it be marked for change detection here? Yes! And this will again update the Input Box on Change Detection cycle. Now, you input 2(input box now contains 12). Again It will be marked for Change Detection. Now, you input 3(The input should had contained 123) but because of your logic, it is changed to 99. So what changes actually? The data in the `value` property. Now your input box contains 99. You enter another 0. What happens? Your setter logic will make `value` to 99.(But wait it was already 99). So Is is it marked for Change detection? No. So will the Input which is bound to `value` see any difference? No.

Note: At least one change detection cycle should run on all your input events in the input box.

How I solved your problem is (I have used property `data` instead of `value`):

```
constructor(private _cdr: ChangeDetectorRef) {}

@Input() set data(v) {

  this._v = v; // I am assigning whatever value I get to the data property
               // so that in the manual change detection a change can be seen
               // (even though that change doesn't need to be show) 
  this._cdr.detectChanges();
  if (v > 99) {
    v = 99
  }
  else if (v < 0) {
    v = 0
  }
  this._v = v
  this.valueChange.emit(v);
}
```

In the very first step, I am assigning whatever value I get from the input box to `_v`, then I call a manual change detection before proceeding with my logic. So the value of `data` is updated with the `Input Value`. My logic will revert it back to `99 or 0`, it will be marked for change detection now, and your view will be updated apprpriately (Note: Your output will emit the final value itself.)

See the working example here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-custom-number-input?file=src/app/hello.component.ts

Answer (score 2):

I don't where is the error but this should work.

```
   <input type="number" style="width: 100px" [(ngModel)]="value" oninput="this.value = this.value > 99?99:this.value" min="0" max="99" />
```

If 99 is not fixed

```
<input type="number" style="width: 100px" 
  [(ngModel)]="value" 
 (keypress)='inputChanged()'
  min="0" max="99" />
```

in your .ts file

```
 export class AppInput {
      maxNumber = 50 // u want to only change this;
      maxNumberBackup = this.maxNumber;

      _v: number;

    constructor(){
      this.maxNumber = this.maxNumber -1;
    }
      inputChanged() {
        return this.value > this.maxNumber ? false : true;
      }

      @Input()
      get value(): number {
        return this._v;
      }
      set value(v) {
        if (v > this.maxNumberBackup) {
          v = this.maxNumberBackup;
        }
        this._v = v;
        this.valueChange.emit(v);
      }
      @Output() valueChange = new EventEmitter<number>();
    }
```

Comment: do I understand it right that we are bypassing angular here? could I access also angular component somehow - e.g. value 99 is not fixed?

Comment: you can replace  99 with a variable.

Comment: This is a nice workaround, but it would be interesting to know why it does happen

Comment: yeah. it can be a bug. :)

Comment: @Asanka I tried your extended solution here https://codesandbox.io/s/6x3z0ww33z - but getting `maxNumber is not defined` Not sure if you can combine angular and DOM events...

Comment: yes it is not take ts files variables. so i find another way. i have edited the code.this is working

Comment: thanks, you both with @Ashish provide me working solutions and I can't accept both. I consider his solution more "angular" way, your is more JS oriented. Thus I will upvote your answer but mark his answer as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to validate length use maxLength instead should work.

```
  <input type="text" style="width: 100px" [(ngModel)]="value" maxLength="2" />
```

Comment: value `99` is just example - could be `50` or anything else